# PHP Search in array for value between two given dates

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            ['s_date'] => 1/1/1989
            ['e_date'] => 6/30/1989
            ['rate'] => 7.92
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['s_date'] => 7/1/1989
            ['e_date'] => 12/31/1989
            ['rate'] => 8.18
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            ['s_date'] => 1/1/1990
            ['e_date'] => 6/30/1990
            ['rate'] => 7.14
        )
```

So I want to search for `rate` between two given dates but I am not sure how to go about with that, i looked into `array_search` function but it didn't help.

```
function findRate($startDate, $endDate) {
  // not sure here what needs to be done...
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: @dev02 what you have tried please show us ?

Comment: @JohnConde: Yes I do try (if you see my previous answers/questions) but iam totally lost at this one so thought of getting help from SO community :(

Comment: @JohnConde You missed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612635/dropdown-mysql-php  Is there a place where i can copy&paste your comment (seems generic) with links?

Comment: @dev02 Do you know how to iterate over an array an access keys/vaules? Do you know how to use `date()` & `strtotime()`? Do you know how to write a good function?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I created a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/79ahm0jj) for it. Happy copy and pasting!

Comment: @JohnConde Thnx.

Comment: Look into array mapping and the `DateTime` PHP class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only to give you a direction, you question is a little unclear, when it comes to your function declaration. Why 2 dates for the lookup?

So i did this

```
function findRate($date,$array){
 $rate=null;
 foreach($yourArray as $value){
  $s=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value['s_date']));
  $e=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value['e_date']));
  if($s<=$lookup && $lookup<=$e){
    $result = $value['rate'];
  }
 }
 return $rate;
}

$rate = findRate('1989-02-02',$yourarrayfromabove);//Result  8.18
```

Try to understand everthing i do here and extent and change if needed.

And open the next question whit self written code, thnx